# Can I put limit on creation of threads in ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, threadpool, download

I am creating an windows phone 8 app which download image thumbnails. Each thumbnail is downloaded on a thread from thread pool. When there are many images (say 100) then phone performance decreases because of large number of threads downloading thumbnails.

Is there a way by which I can control the number of threads created in thread pool at a time?

Comment: We would need to see how you are launching the threads to answer this question.  **You provide this information and I will remove the downvote.**

Comment: Indeed there's a way - just don't create them! You're in control, aren't you?

Comment: Why use the threadpool? You could use Tasks to perform the same thing without consuming too many threads from the threadpool.

Comment: How would that help? Each task uses one thread from the threadpool.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Well, no, that's not strictly true.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, you cannot control how many threads are in the thread pool.  You can however control how many threads your app is using.  Instead of just looping through a list of images you need to download, and firing off tasks (or however you're doing it).  Create `X` number of threads or tasks, wait for those to finish, then fire off more.

Answer (score 0):

You can not control the amount threads in thread pool, as already said, but you can create a custom [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that will run only a certain number of tasks simultaneously. You can find examples from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the below code as example. Here we made the threads into chunks and each chunk will have 32 threads. hope this will help you.

```
int noofthread = accounts.Length;
int startindex = 0;
int endindex = 32;

/* Runs the threads in 32 item chunks */
try
{
    int noofchunk = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double)noofthread / 32.00));

    if (noofthread < endindex)
        endindex = noofthread;
    for (int chunk = 0; chunk < noofchunk; chunk++)
    {
        List<ManualResetEvent> doneEvents = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

        for (int i = startindex; i < endindex; i++)
        {
            int accountID = Convert.ToInt32(accounts[i].Id, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string accountName = Convert.ToString(accounts[i].Name, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

            //List AccountID : AccountNames as they're running
            AddTransactionRecord(new StackFrame(true), accountID + ":" + accountName);

            //Create RunDate
            ReportingService.Date reportDate = new ReportingService.Date();
            reportDate.Day = _appSettings.ReportDate.Day;
            reportDate.Month = _appSettings.ReportDate.Month;
            reportDate.Year = _appSettings.ReportDate.Year;

            // Create object of your class
            Class c = new Class();
            doneEvents.Add(c.DoneEvent);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c.ThreadPoolCallback, i);
        }

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents.ToArray());
        startindex += 32;
        endindex += 32;
        if (endindex > noofthread)
        {
            endindex = noofthread;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads can help you